# How to call a CakepPHP 3 action from JQuery

Tags: jquery, cakephp, controller, call, action

I'm trying to build a custom Dialog using JQuery UI, I need this Dialog to be a generic Dialog (allowing me to load it from many views) with two buttons. I want to send it the controller name, the action name and the parameters, and when the user press the OK button I call the controller action passing the parameters but I don't know how to achieve it.

I have no problems building the dialog, the problems come trying to call the controller from JQuery, I have tried something like this but it doesn't work:

```
function showDialog(controller, action, params){
    $( function() {
        $( "#main-dialog" ).dialog({
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Ok: function() {
                $.ajax({ url: "http://" + domain.name + "/" + controller + "/" + action + "/" + params });
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            },
            Cancel: function(){
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
        });
    } );
}
```

Comment: Can you post the error you are receiving

Comment: I'm not receiving any error, simply the link doesn't work, Javascript console says that the domain attribute doesn't exists, but I tried manually adding the full url with no difference.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
url  = '<?php echo $this->html->url(array('controller'=>'YourController','action'=>'YourAction')) ?>'
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it like this:

```
function showDialog(controller, action){
    var url = "http://" + document.domain + "/" + controller + "/" + action;
    // ...Loop through the received parameters and attach them to the "url" (using the required separator)
    $( function() {
        $( "#main-dialog" ).dialog({
            modal: true,    
            buttons: {
                Ok: function() {
                    window.open(url,"_self");
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                },
                Cancel: function(){
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
             }
        });
    });
}
```